# How to submit sitemap.xml using Java to Google Webmaster?

Tags: search-engine, google-search-console

Is there any way to upload/send dynamic `sitemap.xml` file with updated links to Google Webmaster via its API?  It is throwing lot of errors, unable to proceed.

I also tried http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fsitemap1.xml, a ping mechanism, but it is not reflecting in Google Webmaster Dashboard after multiple(`sitemap2.xml`, `sitemap3.xml`) submits.

Answer (score 0):

So you have followed the below details:

Look at the protocol of submitting a sitemap via the [Google Webmaster Tools API](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol?hl=zh-CN#Sitemaps_Submitting).

[This](http://code.google.com/apis/webmastertools/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#AddingSitemaps) is an example of it is down with Java but I would imagine you could use VB, PHP etc to do this also.

Let us know how it goes.